# Fuzzy substring search within a sentence and scoring the results?

Tags: self-study, text-mining

I have a scenario wherein I am expected to search a large array of sentences for a particular phrase and then display the results based on a descending order of score. My question is about suggestions on approaches for a robust scoring algorithm. I am not worried about the absolute value of the score as long as the scoring algorithm is consistent enough for me to do a relative comparison.
Examples below:

**Example 1**

*sentence 1:* **autotrader** is a medium sized company

*sentence 2:* **auto trader** is a medium sized company

*query:* Autotrader

*Expected scoring:* **Sentence 1** should have a higher score than Sentence 2 because a full match was found

---

**Example 2**

*sentence 1:* **Auto Trader** is a very large company

*sentence 2:* John is a **trader** of **auto** components

*query:* Autotrader

*Expected scoring:* **Sentence 1** should have a higher score than Sentence 2 because a larger fraction of the query was found

---

**Example 3**

*sentence 1:* **Auto Trader** is a very large company

*sentence 2:* **Trader Auto**  is not a company I am aware of

*query:* Autotrader

*Expected scoring:* **Sentence 1** should have a higher score than Sentence 2

---

**Example 4**

*sentence 1:* **J.P. Morgan** is a large company

*sentence 2:* **Morgan**  Freeman is an American actor

*query:* JP Morgan

*Expected scoring:* **Sentence 1** should have a higher score than Sentence 2

---

**Example 5**

*sentence 1:* **ubs** is a large financial company

*sentence 2:* There are not many p**ubs**  near my office

*query:* UBS

*Expected scoring:* **Sentence 1** should have a higher score than Sentence 2 because the term **ubs** is found as a whole word

---

**Example 6**

*sentence 1:* **Morgan Stanley** is a large financial company

*sentence 2:* **Morgan** is a common surname whereas **Stanley** is a popular first name.

*query:* Morgan Stanley

*Expected scoring:* **Sentence 1** should have a higher score than Sentence 2 because both the fragments in  **Morgan Stanley**  are found in close proximity.

---

**EDIT** I wonder if creating a Lucene index out of the sentences and then letting Lucene do the search work.